# How to create a vue-router route in the following format /var1--var2/

Tags: regex, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I'm working with VueRouter and I need to create a dynamic route to handle routes structured like
`/variable1--variable2/`

I'm unsure why the URL structure is set this way instead of just `/variable1/variable2` but it is what it is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. It is actually ridiculously simple and exactly the same as normal routing. I must have had a typo when I tried it earlier. For anyone who may be curious an example would be:

Route Example

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/:var1--:var2', , component: DesiredComponent }
];
```

Linking to the route

```
<router-link :to="{ path:  '/' + var1 + '--' + var2 }">
    Link Text
</router-link>
```